# Which probabilities to rely on?

Tags: probability

In a hypothetical situation, you are trying to determine whether your landlord is a fraud. You know that 1% of landlords are frauds. But then, you also find out that your landlord is a gambler and 20% of gamblers are frauds.

a) Which probability do you rely on to determine whether your landlord is a fraud?

b) Let's say I give a new information that 5% of landlords are gamblers, would your answer change? What would the probability that your landlord is a fraud be?

A random scenario that I think of. Hopefully someone can help me understand the statistics behind it.

For part (a), intuitively, you would want to say that the probability is 20% as it is a higher number and you want to be conservative in your estimation. But then, you can rethink the scenario as 99% of landlords are non-frauds and 80% of gamblers are non-frauds. If you go with the higher number, then you rely on the 99% non-fraud or 1% fraud.

For part (b), I wonder that if you introduce a new information such as 5% of landlords are gamblers, would there be some kind of Bayesian probability that would put the fraud probability somewhere between 1% and 20%.

Comment: Here is the problem expressed as conditional probabilities. I couldn't solve it, and I don't think it's possible without additional info or assumptions: **Events**:   $F$: the person is a fraud;   $L$: the person is a landlord; $G$: the person is a gambler | **Information given**: $P(F|L)=0.01$; 
$P(F|G)=0.2$; 
 b) $P(G|L)=0.05$; **Question**: 
$P(F|G, L) = ?$

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with part (b)

For Part (b), you use Bayes Theorem. There's a 95% chance he is not a gambler, and if you know he is not a gambler, the chance he's frauding you is only 1%. if he is a gambler (a 5% chance), then the chances he's a fraud go up to 20%. Basically, you take a weighted average of the two probabilities with this equation:

.95*.01 + .05*.20

This comes out to .0195, or 1.95%.

Now, for Part (a), we use the same set up. Since we know he's a gambler, the probability he's a gambler is 100% and the probability that he's not a gambler is 0%. We can take our equation from before and modify it with these new probabilities:

0*.01 +1.0*.20

This gets us the intuitive 20%